# WebLogic 12c: persistent store api for use in own java code

Tags: java, weblogic

I'd like to use the weblogic persistent store from own java code deployed to WebLogic 12c. While there is plenty of information on how to configure persistent stores, I found nothing about using them from own code, like official Oracle documentation or code example or at least a javadoc. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into JMX resources like the following? http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_weblogic_jms_resources_in_jmx.htm What do you mean by "using" the persistent store from your own code? You want to open it and read it?

Comment: That's right, my question is not about administration or configuration by different means than admin console or WSTL but using that store for reading and writing from and to that store.

Comment: I don't think it's going to be easy - here is someone that took a look into it: http://www.tomecode.com/2011/02/01/dumping-the-content-or-data-from-weblogic-persistent-store-filestore/ - not sure if an API even exists for the jms persistent datastores

Comment: many thanks for the link to the code sample. Had a quick look on it and yes, this is probably not going to be easy. If these API are private to Oracle, it's probably quite risky to rely on that. Again, many thanks. Got some stuff to read now :-)

Comment: Hi ekatus! Any updates? Did you get this to work?